# How can I create a button to send notifications to OneSignal?

Tags: php, onesignal

Is it possible to create a button whose click will send my users notifications on their Android app from my PHP website. I already have a OneSignal account attached to my app. I just want to send it from my website, not through OneSignal dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [OneSignal REST API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference).

Here is an example extracted from OneSignal REST API Docs:

```
function sendMessage() {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => 'English Message'
    );
    $hashes_array = array();
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "like-button",
        "text" => "Like",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "like-button-2",
        "text" => "Like2",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
        'included_segments' => array(
            'All'
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        'contents' => $content,
        'web_buttons' => $hashes_array
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode($return);

$data = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($data);
$id = $data['id'];
print_r($id);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
```